# Sending a JavaScript variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I am trying to store the date inside a database and to do so I need to pass the variable 'date' to the PHP file `store.pro.php` however, I am not sure how to do this. I have tried Ajax but at the moment it doesn't seem to be working.

Javascipt code:

```
// variables for fetching current date
n = new Date();
y = n.getFullYear();
m = n.getMonth() + 1;
d = n.getDate();

// variables for displaying current date
let displayDay = 0;
let displayMonth = 0;

// If m or d are only one digit, add a leading 0 to the value
if (d < 10) {
  displayDay = '0' + d.toString();
} else {
  displayDay = d.toString();
}

if (m < 10) {
  displayMonth = '0' + m.toString();
} else {
  displayMonth = m.toString();
}

// storing the current date within raceDate
var date = displayDay + '/' + displayMonth + '/' + y;

$.ajax({
  url: "processes/store.pro.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { x: date }
});
```

PHP code in `store.pro.php`

```
if (isset($_POST['x'])) {
  $raceDate = $_POST['x'];

  echo($raceDate);
} else {
  echo "no";
}
```

Comment: Not everything in programming is called "parsing". You meant "passing". (Duplicate question title filter?)

Answer (score 2):

How do you know "it doesn't seem to be working" ?

add success method to your ajax, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "processes/store.pro.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { x: date },
  success: function(res) {
      res = JSON.parse(res);
      console.log(res);
  }
});
```

Then, in  store.pro.php put this:

```
if (isset($_POST['x'])) {
  $raceDate = $_POST['x'];

  echo json_encode($raceDate);
} else {
  echo json_encode("no");
}
exit; // You may need remove this line, after you check, that ajax call is working
```

and check console in your browser

Comment: Sorry but I am pretty new to PHP and so im not quite sure how to check the console in my browser. However, I added your code and I'm still returned with 'no'. Do I need to do something specific to use Ajax?